# SCSS variables are rendered as browser hacks

Tags: sass, scss-lint, stylelint

I've configured stylelint to read SCSS and I keep getting browser hack warnings on SCSS items like `$variables` and `!default`. I loaded in the stylelint-scss plugin thinking this might fix it but it hasn't. I want the browser hacks rule to be enabled for true browser hacks but I'll have to turn this off if it fails on all of the SCSS items.

Does anyone know how I can keep the browser hack rule enabled but not have it fail on non-browser hacks like the standard variables for SCSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The no-browser-hacks rule is not compatible with SCSS syntax. This is documented in the [rule's README](http://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/no-browser-hacks/).

I can think of three options available to you:

1. Continue to use SCSS and turn off the no-browser-hacks rule.
2. Continue to use SCSS and contribute SCSS compatibility to [stylehacks](https://github.com/ben-eb/stylehacks) (the underlying library that powers the rule). The author of the library [is happy to accept](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-scss/issues/60#issuecomment-235269298) a Pull Request for this.
3. Discontinue using SCSS in favour of using standard CSS syntax and constructs.

Adding the stylelint-scss plugin will not resolve the issue as it provides *additional* rules specific to SCSS syntax and constructs. It does not change stylelint's core rules.